# Socket.io and React: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am a relative newcomer to React and implementing a chat app with react, socket.io, and node.
When the user is chatting with someone, he would connect to a socket. It works fine, but if the user leaves to another page, and RE-ENTERS the same chat again, a second socket is connected(bad), and I get the "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" error.

I did implement code to have socket leave the room (on the second useEffect), if the user leaves the page. But that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance,

Error:
[image]

Partial React frontend code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      socket.emit("enter chatroom", { conversationId: props.chatId });
      setChatId(props.chatId);

      getMessagesInConversation(props.chatId, (err: Error, result: any) => {
        if (err) {
          setCerror(err.message);
        } else {
          setMessages(buildMessages(result.messages).reverse());
        }
      });

    socket.on("received", (data: any) => {
      setMessages((messages: any) => {
        console.log("messages");
        console.log(messages);
        return [...messages.slice(-4), ...buildMessages(data.newMsg)];
      });

    });

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      socket.emit("leaveChatroom", {
        conversationId: chatId,
      });
    };
  }, [chatId]);
```

simplified nodejs code

```
  private ioMessage = () => {
    this._io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("socket io connected");
      const socketUser = socket.request.user;

      socket.on("enter chatroom", (data) => {
        const room_status = Object.keys(socket.rooms).includes(
          data.conversationId
        );
        if (!room_status) { // should only join if socket is not already joined.
          socket.join(data.conversationId);
        }
      });


      socket.on("leaveChatroom", (data) => {
        socket.leave(data.conversationId);
      });


      socket.on("chat message", async (msg) => {
        const database = getDB();
        const newMessage = {
          ...msg,
          createdAt: Date.now(),
        };
        await database.collection("message").insertOne(newMessage);
        const messages = await database
          .collection("message")
          .find({ conversationId: msg.conversationId })
          .toArray();

        this._io.to(msg.conversationId).emit("received", {
          newMsg: [messages[messages.length - 1]],
        });

      });

      socket.on("disconnect", (socket) => {
        delete this._users[socketUser.userId];
        console.log("--- disconnect : ", socketUser);
        console.log("--- active users: ", this._users);
      });
    });
  };
```

detailed error log:

[image]